# How to remove insert score button after a judge inputted a score for a specific contestant without affecting the other judges submit button?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

How can I remove the submit button after a judge inputted a score for a specific contestant without affecting the other judges submit button?

So here is the instance. There are different judges to score for specific contestants, using different laptops. What I want to happen is after a judge scores a contestant, the insert score button should disappear without affecting the other judges button.

But my problem is everytime another judge scores for a contestant, the insert score also disappears.

Table 'tbl_rate'

```
---------------------------------
rate_id  judge_id  cont_id  score
---------------------------------
14      | 36     |     5 |  10
---------------------------------
```

Table 'contestants'

```
id  event_id  name  gender  address  date_created  submitted
------------------------------------------------------------
5     | 25  |john doe |male |Texas |  2017-03-06|   1
------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I did is when a judge scores a contestant, the 'submitted' field will become `1` and the submit button will disappear if the 'submitted' field is `1`.

The database is centralized that is why its difficult.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your buttons should have unique id and on scoring use those IDs to hide them by triggering some event function on their click which set their display to none

Comment: How should i implement your suggestion sir?

Comment: see the answer by Vbudo . Jquery can solve your issue but if you are not familiar with Jquery you can use plain JavaScript too.

Comment: Can you please simplify your suggestion ? Im new to all of this, especially Javascript ....

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, Jquery might be an option for you.

```
<button class="vanish" id="5|25|john doe|male" >Make me vanish</button>
```

Then in Jquery

```
$(".vanish").click(function(){
        var theID = $(this).attr("id");
        var partsArray = theID.split('|');  // parse on delimiter
        var whatever0 = partsArray[0]; //get all the values
        var whatever1 = partsArray[1];
              $.post('./insertInDatabase.php',
                { 
                'whatever0' : whatever0, 
                'whatever1' : whatever1,
                    },
                    function (response, status) {

                                        // hide of successful insert
                                         $('#'+ theId).hide();

                                        } // end response 
                         );  // end post

            });
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_post

Comment: hello sir, where can I get id="5|25|john doe|male" ? how can i get it ?

Comment: What do you mean get it?  Have you been able to use each judges values to set up ids for your buttons?  You have to do that first.

Comment: The process of my submission to the database is like this sir, <?php echo form_open('judge/create/' . $this->uri->segment(3)); ?>

Comment: $data = array(
         'judge_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
         'cont_id'=> $id,
            'score' => $this->input->post('score')
        );          $this->model_judge->set_news($data);          public function set_news($data)
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
  $this->db->insert('tbl_rate', $data);